# Replacing fragments blocks the animation of the drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, navigation-drawer

I've added a navigation drawer to my applicaton, it's one single activity that manage 3 fragments.
Now when I click in an item from the navigation drawer list, I get the position of selected item and I call the following method to display the selected fragment :

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new NearbyFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        replaceFragment(fragment);

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
}
```

and here is the `replaceFragment()` method :

```
private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    String backStateName =  fragment.getClass().getName();
    String fragmentTag = backStateName;

    boolean fragmentPopped = mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate (backStateName, 0);

    if (!fragmentPopped && mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) == null){
        //fragment not in back stack, create it.
        FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragmentTag);
        //ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right); 
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

the problems:
     when I click the home menu (case 0), the navigation closes with a smooth animation without any problems.
     But when I select the map or nearby menu (case 1 and 2), the animation stops waiting for the fragment to load.

I want to use `AsyncTask`, to replace the fragment in a background thread but I don't know how
if only someone could explain to me what exactly should I do, or has a better idea it would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you implement your `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, the framework provides callbacks on close & open of the drawer:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        /* replaceFragment() should be called here */
        replaceFragment(fragment);
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        /* do nothing here */
    }
};
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

So your `displayView()` method should look like this:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
        case 1:
        fragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new NearbyFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        //replaceFragment(fragment);

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
}
```

What I have done here is call `replaceFragment()` in the callback for drawer closed.

Try this. This should work.